# Loading a pdf document using absolute path

Tags: c#

I have a requirement where i want to load pdf document in a web page from a physical path. The pdf document location is not inside my website directory. To elaborate on this with example: Let assume my virtual directory refers to "c:\website". I have all my pdf documents stored under different folder called c:\pdfDocuments". On one of my web page i want to load my pdf document from c:\pdfdocuments. Is there way to pass the absolute path in this case (c:\pdfdocuments\x.pdf) to frame control's src attribute.

Thanks
CS

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258517/reference-file-outside-of-web-site-directory

Comment: Thanks.. yes you are correct. That's exactly what i am looking for. That post answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that unless the C:\pdfdocuments is also a website; and in that case you would need to pass in the URL that relates to that physical path.

Keep in mind that the frame, or other html element, is trying to load the contents of the file accross the internet from the browser to your server.  The browser on the clients end has no knowledge nor access to your physical filesystem, only what is exposed via the web server.

Now, if you're trying to load this on the server side, then you should be able to use the physical path as long as the worker process has access permissions to that path.  But based on the question ".. to frame control's src attribute." I'm assuming you're referring the the client side html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am in fact trying to assign the src attribute property on server side. I am using C# and using following code to assign document location:

 fram1.Attributes["src"] = "c:\pdfdocuments\x.pdf". for some reason when page is loaded the fram1 is blank.

Thanks

Comment: This has the same effect essentially, it just causes the generation of the HTML on the client side to have a: <... src="c:\pdfdocuments\x.dpf"> on the client site.  It still results in the client browser trying to access an absolute path on your web server (which it can't).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to use one of the work around suggested in link by dthorpe.