# pdf.js by andreasgal does not load pdf using absolute path. Works only with relative paths

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am using a javascript library to renders pdf files using a browser.

This is the one:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

I cannot get it working with absolute paths as the path to the PDF I want to display. Altough relative paths works fine.

This call does not work:

```
PDFView.open("D:/Projects/Empenho/Pdf1.pdf", 0);
```

With relative path I managed to have it working properly:

`PDFView.open("https://localhost/MyPDFs/Pdf1.pdf", 0);`

**open() function:**

```
function getDocument(source) {
  var workerInitializedPromise, workerReadyPromise, transport;

  if (!source.url) 
      error('Invalid parameter array, need either .data or .url');


  workerInitializedPromise = new PDFJS.Promise();
  workerReadyPromise = new PDFJS.Promise();
  transport = new WorkerTransport(workerInitializedPromise, workerReadyPromise);

  console.log(workerReadyPromise);

  workerInitializedPromise.then(function transportInitialized() {
      transport.fetchDocument(source);
  });

  return workerReadyPromise;
};
```

As long the system has not a good debug system nor a good documentation I can´t find out where the problem lies.

I believe there is somenthing related to the workerReadyPromise as I can print the object and see differences when using absolte x relative path.
When I use absolute path the workerReadyPromise state is that:

http://pbrd.co/10VGnuQ
Any Idea?

PS. I am not sure if this is the same case, but found this:

[Loading a pdf document using absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258696/loading-a-pdf-document-using-absolute-path)

Comment: `https://localhost/MyPDFs/Pdf1.pdf` this is ablolute url and its relative equivalent is ,`/MyPDFs/Pdf1.pdf`, the problem you could not use local filesystem paths like this "D:/Projects/Empenho/Pdf1.pdf" use server based paths instead.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that pdf.js, gets the file you specify using AJAX.

You cannot use local file paths for AJAX requests and that seems to be where you are having problems

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933834/using-ajax-to-access-web-from-local-file) explains why.